# Posterior and Predictive Density

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, posterior

Let X1 be a claim from an auto insurance policy. Suppose X follows an exponential distribution with rate lambda, where lambda follows a gamma distribution with mean 2 and variance 2. What is the posterior and predictive densities?

I think the thing that's throwing me off with this problem is that there's no n given. How would I approach this without knowing n?

Comment: I suspect they want you to do the math, not solve for a particular set of numbers.  When you do the math, you can just specify a sample of size $n$ without it being tied to a specific value and work through it to get the posterior distribution, where $n$ is one of the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you mean
\begin{align}
\Pr(\Lambda \in S\subseteq [0,+\infty) ) & = \int_S \lambda e^{-\lambda} \, d\lambda \\[10pt]
\text{and } \Pr(X>x\mid\Lambda) & = e^{-\Lambda x} \text{ for } x\ge0.
\end{align}
and you are looking for $\Pr(\Lambda \in S\mid X).$

There's nothing called $\text{“}n\text{''}$ involved. Sometimes $n$ is used as the size of an i.i.d. sample where the conditional distribution given $\Lambda$ of each observation in the sample is the conditional distribution of $X$ given $\Lambda$ as stated above. If that's what is meant, then one could say that in this case, $n=1.$

Then one can say that the likelihood function is
$$
L(\lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}
$$
and then since the prior is
$$
\lambda e^{-\lambda} \, d\lambda \text{ for } \lambda \ge0,
$$
the posterior is
$$
\text{constant} \times \lambda^2 e^{-2\lambda} \text{ for }\lambda \ge 0.
$$
That is a gamma distribution.

Comment: +1 but you seem to have just OP's homework at the end there; guidance could be given without actually depriving the student of the benefit of solving it.